# How to clear array after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to clear array after form submit. I want to prevent duplicate selection in jquery autocomplete, in which pre-selected values can be saved in an array, which prevents re-selection.

And by deleting a selected row it should delete the selected value from the array.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  inArray = [];
});
$('#formSubmit').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#formSubmit")[0].reset();
});
//autocomplete script    
$(document).on('focus', '.search', function() {
  let type = $(this).data('type');

  $(this).autocomplete({
    source: [{
      label: 1,
      value: 1,
      data: {
        t_id: 1,
        Fee: 10
      }
    }, {
      label: 2,
      value: 2,
      data: {
        t_id: 2,
        Fee: 20
      }
    }],
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      let id_num = $(this).attr('id').substring(5);
      var element = ui.item.data.Fee;
      if (inArray.indexOf(element) !== -1) {
        alert('duplicate error');
        return;
      }
      inArray.push(element);
      $(this).val(ui.item.value);
      $('#fee_' + id_num).val(ui.item.data.Fee);
      $('#total').val(ui.item.data.Fee);
      //$(this).attr('data-type', ui.item.type);
      return false;
    },
  });
});

var i = $('table#first tr').length;
$("#more").on('click', function() {
  html = '<tr>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="type" id="test_' + i + '" class="search" placeholder="Enter 1 or 2 only"> </td>';
  html += '<td><input type="number" id="fee_' + i + '" class="fee" placeholder="Fee"></td>';
  html += '<td><p class="delete"> delete </p> </td>';
  html += '</tr>';
  $('table#first').append(html);
  i++;
});
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function() {
  $(this).parents("tr").remove();
});
```

```css
#button {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!--hidden div-->
<form id="formSubmit" method="post">
  <table id="first">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Fee</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" data-type="type" id="test_1" class="search" placeholder="Enter 1 or 2 only"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="fee_1" class="fee" placeholder="Fee"></td>
        <td><a id="more"> More Row </a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button type="submit" id="button"> submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: What you have tried? Please share code snippet.

Comment: @mplungjan I was trying to add code in snippet tool. but the question mistakenly posted .

Comment: @Phantom question updated with code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have an `inArray` variable declared globally. So, `onSumbit` you can just empty that array.
And to delete specific element in array please check the comments in JS code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  inArray = [];
});
$('#formSubmit').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#formSubmit")[0].reset();
 inArray = [];
});
//autocomplete script    
$(document).on('focus', '.search', function() {
  let type = $(this).data('type');

  $(this).autocomplete({
    source: [{
      label: 1,
      value: 1,
      data: {
        t_id: 1,
        Fee: 10
      }
    }, {
      label: 2,
      value: 2,
      data: {
        t_id: 2,
        Fee: 20
      }
    }],
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      let id_num = $(this).attr('id').substring(5);
      var element = ui.item.data.Fee;
      if (inArray.indexOf(element) !== -1) {
        alert('duplicate error');
        return;
      }
      inArray.push(element);
      $(this).val(ui.item.value);
      $('#fee_' + id_num).val(ui.item.data.Fee);
      $('#total').val(ui.item.data.Fee);
      //$(this).attr('data-type', ui.item.type);
      return false;
    },
  });
});

var i = $('table#first tr').length;
$("#more").on('click', function() {
  html = '<tr>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="type" id="test_' + i + '" class="search" placeholder="Enter 1 or 2 only"> </td>';
  html += '<td><input type="number" id="fee_' + i + '" class="fee" placeholder="Fee"></td>';
 
 // DATA ID IS USED TO GET "VALUE" IN TR TO BE REMOVED
  html += '<td><p class="delete" data-id="fee_' + i + '"> delete </p> </td>';
  html += '</tr>';
  $('table#first').append(html);
  i++;
});
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function() {  
 
 // GETTING VALUE IN INPUT USING DATA-ID ATTRIBUTE
 let rem = $('#'+$(this).attr('data-id')).val();
 // FINDING INDEX OF VALUE IN ARRAY
 let index = inArray.indexOf(+rem);
 
 if(index > -1) {
  // IF VALUE IS IN ARRAY REMOVE IT FROM ARRAY
  inArray.splice(index, 1);
 }
 
 // FINALLY REMOVE TR FROM DOM
 $(this).parents("tr").remove();
});
```

```css
#button {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!--hidden div-->
<form id="formSubmit" method="post">
  <table id="first">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Fee</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" data-type="type" id="test_1" class="search" placeholder="Enter 1 or 2 only"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="fee_1" class="fee" placeholder="Fee"></td>
        <td><a id="more"> More Row </a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button type="submit" id="button"> submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: And if I delete a particular row, How do I remove its value from the array.

Comment: The problem still has not ended delete row, I removed `+` sign from rem `let index = inArray.indexOf(+rem);`  Now it is working. does it matters?

Comment: that `+` is to convert (numeric) string to int. ex. "5" to 5